# Entity Framework MultiTenant Per User

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, multi-tenant

I've applied multi tenant by entity framework core (shared schema , shared database )
and the tenant Id stored in http Context request , it will be resolved after the user login
but most of time tenant Id not changed with different logged in users

My Table :

```
public class Blog
{ 
    private int _tenantId;  

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; } 
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

My  Db Context

```
PUBLIC dbContext:DbContext
{
   PRIVATE int tenantId;
   public dbContext(DbContextOptions<dbContext> options): base(options) { 
        //securityHelper IS EXTERNAL LIBRARY
        this.tenantId = securityHelper.GetClaim<INT>("tenantId");
   }
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      modelBuilder.Entity<AccountsTransactions>().HasQueryFilter(p=>p._tenantId == this.tenantId);
   }
```

}

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @GertArnold I'm asking If I've made some thing wrong , that leads to
the tenantId value is always the same with different users

Comment: *most of time tenant Id not changed with different logged in users* sounds like a fact, not a question. Like, "most users belong to one tenant". But if that's wrong we have nothing here to help you. It all depends on this opaque `securityHelper`.

Comment: Hmm, this is a second post during the last two days which claims the dynamic global filter does not work, so probably needs investigation, since per documentation it should work, except if the real code is different than shown here. Are you using EF Core 5? How do you allocate db context (per request, per call)? Are you using db context pooling? Does `dbContetxt.tenantId` field contain correct (changing) value?

Comment: @GertArnold securityHelper reads the claim of tenant Id from HttpContenxt , no thing else .

Comment: @IvanStoev the real code is not different from the code above , 
I'm using version 5 of Entity frame work and .net core  .
I allocate it per request 
I don't use db context pooling ,
yes it has correct value

Comment: Tried something like this and can't reproduce. As soon as the query filter is using db context instance member like `this.tenantId` field and not some direct static method call, the generated SQL contains parameter (rather than constant value) populated with the value from the db context executing the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error. You defined _tenantId in a Blog class but trying to use it in AccountsTransactions class. Should be like this :

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasQueryFilter(p=>p._tenantId == this.tenantId);
```

but I am amazed how you could reach private _tenandId in " p._tenantId"?

If you define property as private you should use this syntax:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasQueryFilter(p => EF.Property<int>(p, "_tenantId") == this.tenantId);
```